# Expected null({ }) to equal Object({ })

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-resource

I have been trying to run AngularJS own unit tests of $resource. The only difference is that I'm running then with Jasmine v2.0 and Karma v0.13.
I did all the work of converting custom actions from older Jasmine to newer, so all tests pass. Well almost all...

I have stumbled with one type of tests. I believe it have something to do `$httpBackend`. Whilst testing [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ngResource/resourceSpec.js#L445) I see it fails:

`Expected null({  }) to equal Object({  }).`

Actual test code, problem is with latest expectation:

```js
      // ---
      callback = jasmine.createSpy();
      // ---

      it("should create resource", function() {
        $httpBackend.expect('POST', '/CreditCard', '{"name":"misko"}').respond({id: 123, name: 'misko'});

        var cc = CreditCard.save({name: 'misko'}, callback);
        expect(cc).toEqualData({name: 'misko'});
        expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(cc).toEqualData({id: 123, name: 'misko'});
        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
        expect(callback.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toEqual(cc);
        expect(callback.calls.mostRecent().args[1]()).toEqual({});
      });
```

**UPDATE**

Found it.
Turns out, angular uses function bellow to create empty Object. Probably newest versions of Jasmine fails on calling Objects instantiated with `null` and `{}` as equals.

```
/**
 * Creates a new object without a prototype. This object is useful for lookup without having to
 * guard against prototypically inherited properties via hasOwnProperty.
 *
 * Related micro-benchmarks:
 * - http://jsperf.com/object-create2
 * - http://jsperf.com/proto-map-lookup/2
 * - http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-object-keys2
 *
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function createMap() {
  return Object.create(null);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint there to find out what the second argument is?

Comment: If I understood your question, so yes, I did. I tried to call `callback.mostRecentCall.args[1]()` and it indeed results in `null({})` which I have no idea what it means. Meaning, looks like it's an empty Object. Only it's ctor is somehow null, not and Object itself.

Comment: The proper syntax for jasmine 2 would be:
`expect(foo.calls.mostRecent().args[1]).toEqual({});`

Comment: @ronapelbaum yes, sorry, I changed the snippet, anyway: `args[1]` is a function. expectation is to test what the function returns. so it fails with `Expected Function to equal Object({  }).`

Comment: I think that it's best practice to use jasmine matchers: `expect(...).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));`

Comment: not arguing here, but I want to test the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at AngularJS source, I see that sometimes objects are created using `Object.create(null)`, like in a snippet below.

```
/**
 * Creates a new object without a prototype. This object is useful for lookup without having to
 * guard against prototypically inherited properties via hasOwnProperty.
 *
 * Related micro-benchmarks:
 * - http://jsperf.com/object-create2
 * - http://jsperf.com/proto-map-lookup/2
 * - http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-object-keys2
 *
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function createMap() {
  return Object.create(null);
}
```

Looks like Jasmine 2.0 added comparison for prototype type as well, so expectation fails.

Test can be written like this: `expect(callback.calls.mostRecent().args[1]()).toEqual(Object.create(null));`, for it will pass.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a spare `()` in your code. Convert this;

`expect(callback.mostRecentCall.args[1]()).toEqual({});`

to

`expect(callback.mostRecentCall.args[1]).toEqual({});`

Comment: it's exactly how it's written in AngularJS source code. It works there, the difference being older version of Jasmine. Anyway, after removing `()` the error is: `Expected Function to equal Object({  }).`

Comment: Can you run a console log in your test like this:
`console.log(callback.mostRecentCall.args[1])` and post the result.

Comment: sure:
`'callback.calls.mostRecent().args[1]: ', function (name) { ... }`  
`'callback.calls.mostRecent().args[1](): ', Object{}`

Comment: You could try `expect(callback.calls.mostRecent().args[1]()).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object));`

Comment: Yes. It worked, But I don't want to test if it any object, I want it to be empty object. I've found what caused the issue.